# How to scroll ItemsControl vertically inside of the Viewbox?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, scroll, viewbox

How to let ItemsControl scroll vertically, if it's placed in a viewbox?

```
<Viewbox>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="..." />
</Viewbox>
```

I need the Viewbox to scale all the content of my ItemsControl horizontally to the width of the phone (Viewbox does it perfectly, it scales the content in such a way that the widest row of ItemsControl occupies exactly the width, equal to the phone width). But now I cannot scroll the list vertically for some reason, I tried ScrollViewer, scrollbars of Viewbox, scrollbars of ItemsControl -- nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

A `ViewBox` measures its contents, then transforms it so that it fits perfectly within the space available. This will remove the need for scrollbars!

Considering that phones have a fixed screen size, the `ViewBox` is often redundant. Why not just set an explicit size?

Comment: Actually, it's not. In my case Viewbox adjusts the list only horizontally within the phone size, and vertically objects go out of the border.